# Android Facebook get friends graph api example

Tags: android, facebook

I would like to know how i get my facebook friends list in android?I want display facebook friends details on my android app with name and UID.

Thanks

Comment: You call the API /me/friends

Answer (score 0):

I got  correct Answer for this.
it about using request in android facebook sdk

```
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("limit",  "5000");

        final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();   

        new Request(
                session,
                "/me/friends",
                params,
                HttpMethod.GET,
                new Request.Callback() {
                    public void onCompleted(Response response) {

                        try {

                            if (response != null){
                                Log.d("LLLLL", "response: " + response.toString());


                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

}
                    ).executeAsync();

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the "read_friendlists" permission, then you can view all the frien list using the /{user-id}/friendlists command on Facebook Graph API.

Read more about the official documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/friendlist

There is a clear example if you click on: "Graph Explorer".

Comment: that answer is completely wrong. friendlist is different to friends. it´s just access to the lists, but without any friend data.